# Calculate correlation matrix between types

Tags: python, pandas, correlation

I have dataframe `df` which includes 3 columns as follow (tab separeted):

```
X    Y    types
0.3422    0.3214    pen
-0.1784    0.8621    pen
0.9932    0.1347    pencil
0.2847    -0.7634   pen
-0.6548    -0.2981    ruler
0.4792    0.3782    pencil
0.9231    -0.2949    ruler
```

The output would be the correlation matrix like this:

```
      pen    pencil    ruler

pen    C1      C2        C3

pencil C4      C5        C6

ruler  C7      C8        C9
```

I tried `.corr()` but it doesn't work properly with how df being structured

Note: C1 is the correlation value between pen-pen, C2 between pen-pencil and so on.

Any help with that please?

Comment: What should be the value of C1?

Comment: It's the correlation value between pen-pen, C2 between pen-pencil and so on @DaniMesejo

Comment: there are multiple values for pen how do you wanna deal with this?

Comment: Yes, but you have several pencil columns ... and pen columns

Comment: You mean different X and Y for each type, right? I'm not fully sure, what would be the best thing to deal with that? take averge among X and Y for each type? so at the end we would have only 3 rows @ombk

Comment: You mean several rows, as I said in my pervious comment @DaniMesejo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you could do:

```
res = df.groupby('types').mean().T.corr()
```

**Output**

```
types   pen  pencil  ruler
types                     
pen     1.0     1.0    1.0
pencil  1.0     1.0    1.0
ruler   1.0     1.0    1.0
```

You can change the correlation method to fit your needs, for example:

```
import numpy as np
res = df.groupby('types').mean().T.corr(method=np.dot)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
types        pen    pencil     ruler
types                               
pen     1.000000  0.145973 -0.021464
pencil  0.145973  1.000000  0.022724
ruler  -0.021464  0.022724  1.000000
```

By default method will be the pearson correlation, from the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html) on *method*:

> method{‘pearson’, ‘kendall’, ‘spearman’} or callable Method of
> correlation:
>
> pearson : standard correlation coefficient
>
> kendall : Kendall Tau correlation coefficient
>
> spearman : Spearman rank correlation
>
> callable: callable with input two 1d ndarrays and returning a float.
> Note that the returned matrix from corr will have 1 along the
> diagonals and will be symmetric regardless of the callable’s behavior.
>
> New in version 0.24.0.

Comment: indeed i would have gone this way. grouping by type and averaging

Comment: Thanks! but I have question, in the first case when nothing pass to correlation; why all resulted correlation values are 1?

Comment: @LamaMo Updated the answer.